# Cannot receive push notification on iOS from Firebase 3.2.0 topics

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase, swift2

I followed the tutorial by google on https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-topics#receive_and_handle_topic_messages to subscribe to a Firebase topic on my iOS app.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribeToTopic("/topics/Notifications")

    let homeViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())

    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = homeViewController

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

However, when I send a topic push notification out from the Firebase console. I could not receive any push notifications. But when I send out push notification to user segment from the console, the push is working perfectly. When I check the Xcode console, I am seeing this FIRMessaging error.

```
2016-05-31 11:11:47.893: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> Cannot subscribe to topic: /topics/Notifications with token: (null)
```

I've tried to search for this error but have no luck finding anything. I am not sure if this is the problem that is causing my app to not receive any push from topics.

Does anyone have this issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like maybe you're calling `subscribeToTopic` too early.

First, before you set up any Firebase call, make sure you call

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

That will ensure that all Firebase services are properly set up and initialized.

Next, you're going to need to wait just a bit to subscribe to topics. Your client needs to first register your app with both APNs and FCM to ensure that it can receive notifications. That involves a network call, which means you can't subscribe to topics when your app first launches.

Instead, I'd recommend putting that code into your `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` handler instead. Something like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  NSLog(@"Hooray! I'm registered!");
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/cool_users"];
}
```

Edit: And the Swift version...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
  print("Hooray! I'm registered!")
  FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribeToTopic("/topics/swift_fans")
}
```

Comment: Is there an iOS 10 fix for this? Subscribing to topics on iOS 10 does not work.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this code, you should subscribe to `/topics/cool_users` instead of just `cool_users`

Comment: @vnchopra it looks like henmer's answer works. Prefixing with /topics resolves the issue on iOS 10 for me.

Comment: Thanks, @henmer! I've added that prefix in my sample code, too.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to get called (xCode 8.3.3 July 2017).

Comment: According to latest sdk
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) gets called.

Comment: @vnchopra you should use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46431208/2108523

Answer (score 6):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551338/4367291) did not work for me. The token is not always available when `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` is called.
For example if application is freshly installed and starts for the first time `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` returns nil.

You need to make sure application calls `subscribeToTopic:` **after** the token is available.
I ended up with creating a helper object that enqueues `subscribeToTopic:`, `unsubscribeFrom:` calls and executes them in FIFO order after the token arrives.

```
class FIRMessagingHelper {

    private let queue: OperationQueue

    init() {
        queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        queue.addOperation(TokenReadyOperation())
    }

    func subscribeTo(topic: String) {
        queue.addOperation { 
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ 
                FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribeToTopic(topic)
            })
        }
    }

    func unsubscribeFrom(topic: String) {
        queue.addOperation {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                FIRMessaging.messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic(topic)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

TokenReadyOperation waits until the token appears. [AsynchronousOperation](https://github.com/TriforkKRK/TFFoundation/tree/develop/TFFoundation/Concurrency) is used as the base class to minimize boilerplate.

```
class TokenReadyOperation : AsynchronousOperation {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TokenReadyOperation.tokenRefreshed(notification:)),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    override func didStart() {
        finishIfTokenAvailable()
    }

    private func finishIfTokenAvailable() {
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else { return }
        markFinished()
    }

    /// Posted every time token changes
    @objc private func tokenRefreshed(notification: Notification) {
        finishIfTokenAvailable()
    }
}
```

Few things to keep in mind:

- App must call `FIRApp.configure()` or `FIRApp.configureWithOptions(_:)` prior making any Firebase calls (as [Todd Kerpelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005061/todd-kerpelman) mentioned)
- `subscribeToTopic:`, `unsubscribeFrom:` are not thread safe and must be executed on main thread
- Topic names has to be in "/topics/*" format (as [henmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098945/henmer) mentioned)
- Make sure to use different configuration plist for debug and App Store release of your app. See `FIRApp.configureWithOptions(_:)` documentation.
- Date & Time should be current, otherwise the token may not be delivered.
- Make sure to use [the newest framework version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks). I had issues with notification delivery with the SDK released around January 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Listening for the `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` on a fresh install seems to be the only way to prevent topic subscribe failures.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was not solved by calling `subscribeToTopic` after

`func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {`

instead it worked by calling `subscribeToTopic` after

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
```

this function get called when you get your push token from **APNS** not firebase.

Xcode 8.3.2

Swift 3.0