# Sending push notification messages from my NodeJS app is not working

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications from my `NodeJS` server to my `iOS` device but I can't get it to work. I'm doing the `Send to topic` method.  I've tried the code sample from the `Firebase Admin` (NodeJS) documentation but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my NodeJS code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');    // Firebase-admin module to send push notifications via firebase
const serviceAccount = require('./myprivatekey.json'); //privateKey.json file

// setup firebase admin
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: FIREBASE_URL
});

sendMessage('someTopic', 'test message');

function sendMessage(topicName, message) {
    // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
    var topic = `/topics/${topicName}`;
    console.log(topic);

    // See the "Defining the message payload" section below for details
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'test title',
            body: message
        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
}
```

Here's my Swift code to subscribe to the topic:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/someTopic")
    }
```

When I run my NodeJS app, I get the `Successfully sent message:` log so I'm not sure why I'm not receiving the push notification on my iOS device.

And yes, I've already setup the necessary `APN` certificates for both development and production. I am able to send out push notifications from the `Firebase Cloud Messaging` web console and successfully receive the notifications on my `iOS` device. I just can't seem to get my `NodeJS` `Firebase Admin` app to work. Appreciate any help on this.

UPDATE: I also want to point out that even with the Swift code to subscribe to a firebase topic, the specified topic doesn't appear on the Firebase web console. I understand it takes hours to appear on the firebase web console but it's been a week already since I ran code to subscribe my iOS device to a firebase topic.

I've also tried changing my NodeJS code to send to a single device instead of send to topic, and that works. It's just the send to topic that is not working. I've narrowed the possible issue to `send to topic`. Could it be that the Swift code I have is not successfully subscribing my iOS device to the specified topic? But that's the exact snippet I got from the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Did you implement all the code necessary to register devices for remote notifications and receiving topic messages? https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-topics

Comment: @PatNeedham Yes. I can verify this because I can send out push notifications from the Firebase web console and receive the notifications on my iOS device successfully. I just can't seem to receive the notifications from my Node app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out that calling the subscribe code in `viewDidLoad()` is a bad idea as the the app might not have fully connected to the FCM and APN yet at that point in time. So I relocated that code in my `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in the AppDelegate.

Now it is working.

I got the idea from this stackoverflow question thread: [Cannot receive push notification on iOS from Firebase 3.2.0 topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549717/cannot-receive-push-notification-on-ios-from-firebase-3-2-0-topics)

Hope this helps anyone who encounters this issue