# FCM topic - Cannot subscribe to topic: xxx with token: (null) - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting this error from Firebase Messaging API:

```
[Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002010] Cannot subscribe to topic: /topics/testTopic with token: (null)
```

But before:

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/testTopic")
```

I'm printing out the token like this:

```
print("TOKEN: \(InstanceID.instanceID().token() ?? "NO TOKEN")")
```

The result is:

```
TOKEN:cXPhGQ_inE4:APA91bEKZF5depHmIm9gDliCFRCRcnJf5LYy5FMg6nhpWvKU3o3HEtr1WTBHUiCZXT4XzhVg2oqXzhtfrgf83brtLdqXii546644ciMPO80tri4JPueQBClKbaomEfoh54ku8E2lw
```

So the token isn't *null*.

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone some help?

Comment: I've also tested on different devices, but got the same error.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37549717/4815718

Comment: **SOLVED**. Thank you very much!

The problem was that I wanted to subscribe in _didFinishLaunchingWithOptions_ but in that point not all services were setted up. 

The solution was to subscribe in the delegate _didRegisterUserNotificationSettings_.

Comment: I'm seeing this _sometimes_ on iOS 9.3.5, also confirming token exists. Also calling from didRegisterUserNotificationSettings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I wanted to subscribe in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but in that point not all services were set up.
**The solution was** to subscribe in the delegate `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings`.

Comment: I am doing this and still seeing this issue :(

Answer (score 3):

In MessagingDelegate try it:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/testTopic")
}
```

Comment: This might also help, but I've already solved it.Thanks anyway!

Comment: This method does not exist. didRefreshRegistrationToken is the proper method

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. The solution was to invoke `FirebaseApp.configure()` first:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

instead of:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self // this brakes FCM
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most ideal place to resolve this issue is in the MessagingDelegate method didRefreshRegistrationToken.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
   // TODO: subscribe to topics here
}
```